# Pulling values from a list which match specific dates - Excel VBA Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate some help with excel VBA please -

I have 2 data columns on one sheet which also have blanks in between

```
  name         Date
   a        01-01-2019
   c        01-08-2019

   b        01-02-2019
   f        01-01-2019 

. . .
```

I am trying to display these columns organised in date order, without blanks, on another sheet in the same workbook. eg:

```
 name      date
  a       01-01-19
  f       01-01-19
  b       01-02-19
  c       01-08-19
```

I have tried using a For Each loop which contains some If statements, but it is not achieving the desired out come and I think will be very long-winded way of going about it - I'm new to VBA and I am struggling to get loops to work and have the correct result. I have looked at while loops but not sure if this is the correct way to go?

Thanks very much for your time!

Edit: Added in the code so far - (I'm aware it is not good)!

```
Dim r As Range
 Dim t As Range
 Dim r2 As Range
 Dim t2 As Range
 Dim rData As Range
 Set rData = Range("C4:C70") 

 Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4") 
 Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4")  
 Set t = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D4") 
 Set t2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4")  


  For Each r2 In rData 
    If r.Value = "01/09/2018" Then
     t = r  
      t2 = r.Offset(0, -1)
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 
      Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0) 
      Set t = t.Offset(1, 0) 
      Set t2 = t2.Offset(1, 0) 
    End If
   If r.Value <> "" & r2.Value <> "" Then
        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0) 
       Set t = t.Offset(1, 0) 
        Set t2 = t2.Offset(1, 0) 

   End If
    If r.Value = "01/10/2018" Then
     t = r  
     t2 = r.Offset(0, -1)

    End If
  Next r2
```

Comment: Just copy and paste the whole then sort on the date.  The blanks will go the bottom.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your `For Each` loop that you had? It's okay if it doesn't work.

Comment: @dwirony I have added the code but I'm not sure its a good starting point at all!

Comment: Why are you checking for a date? Shouldn't you be checking for blanks? I.E `""`

Comment: Why don't you just copy the whole worksheet and sort by date as Scott suggested?

Comment: @hsquared That's totally fine - people here like to see an attempt made, and you've clearly made one - it's not *bad*, but needs some work :)

Comment: @ScottCraner  I understand why you are saying this, but this sheet is to be used by people who are not used to using excel. The values on sheet1 are pulled in from another sheet via an excel formula. We currently have a copy/paste/filter system like this is place and mistakes are being made by not copying the whole sheet. I'm trying to get a list that automatically displays the list in order to avoid human error.

Comment: Again why not use vba in a worksheet calculate or worksheet change event that copies the whole sheets values over the existing and sort.  It will be quicker than looping.

Comment: You can do this yourself. 1) Record a macro, make a copy of the sheet, and then sort your data. You will then have a working recorded macro to edit down :)

Comment: @urdearboy The original data cannot be simply sorted like this. It is pulled in from other sheets which cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go - a little cleaner than a recorded macro.

```
Sub SortDates()

Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, lastrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

sht2.Range("C1:D" & lastrow).Value = sht.Range("C1:D" & lastrow).Value

sht2.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
sht2.Sort.SetRange Range("C1:D" & lastrow)
sht2.Sort.Apply

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect - thank you very much for taking the time to do this! I have not come across anything like this solution in the research I have done - Didn't know it could be done this way!

Comment: No problem - there are several ways to go about this, but sorting was definitely your best option.

Comment: An extension of this question (Which I have tried with no success) -**Would it be possible to return only the rows which have values in the date column?** In the data there are some which have no dates which I would like not included rather then placed at the bottom. I have tried things like `If cell.Value = "" ` But this doesn't work and I feel its the wrong way to approach it.

Comment: @hsquared yes, we can just clear contents to everything below your last line of dates - how far over do your columns go? Is it just column C and D?

Comment: Ah yes that would make sense. I have modified your answer so it is now B to D columns which are used. But D, the Date column, is the last column with data in.